# Are these shingles properly installed?

Tags: roof, shingles

I just had the shingles on my roof replaced with BP Everest 42 shingles. The old shingles were removed, new flashing, waterproof underlaying, etc was installed. My concern is really in the final product: it just doesn't look that great to me (or my wife, who actually thought this was the old roof still and they hadn't finished).

[image]
[image]
[image]

You'll probably have to view the zoomed in images to see it, but to me it looks kind of uneven and wavy, with the edges butted together at strange places.

Is this actually a poor job, and poor enough that I should bring it up as an issue, or am I just being overly critical? I haven't talked to anyone from the company yet as they just finished; I just want some other opinions first as I'll be a non-roofer arguing with a professional.

Comment: From the photos I don't see anything out of line , it will take a couple of warm days for the shingles to relax. Are the rows nice and straight? Can't tell from the photos. The few shingles I can tell where they are butted together look to be over a solid section. This style is designed to look like what we see a irigular pattern some folks really like it. Where the edges are up on the caps they will relax and lay down with a few warm days but I don't see anything wrong from this angle.

Comment: @EdBeal The rows are straight. It's more the parts sticking up I was concerned about. I don't think the temperature has gotten above ~12°C (53°F) since install, so maybe that's it.

Comment: I think they will relax with a little time or a warm day, putting comp shingles down when cool takes a little time for them to settle it will look better

Comment: Those look like "Architectural shingles" to me, and the uneven 'stepped' profile is deliberate.

Comment: They left a rubber band on the roof, have them come back out and remove it.

Answer (score 2):

Looking at the photos provided, I don’t see anything that qualifies as a bad job. My guess is that if they’re newly laid shingles they probably just need to be exposed to some more sunlight/heat so they lay down properly, but that’s perfectly normal and nothing to worry about.

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 things to worry about with architectural/dimensional shingles.

1. The only way the manufacturer will honor a warranty claim is if the shingles are installed in a stair step pattern.
2. The most common roofing mistake is having the air pressure too high which will send the nail thru the first shingle layer and possible thru the second layer as well. This will cause your shingles to "slide" once the roof gets hot enough. This is a common issue on steep roofs, 8/12 pitch or higher.

Obviously, we want straight runs, but if the 2 things I mentioned are/were adhered to, I wouldn't fret too much about wavy runs.

From the last pic you posted, a close-up, it does NOT look like the shingles were stair stepped...